# OMP Analysis of Water Mass in Matlab, "Index exceeds matrix dimensions."

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, contour

I am quite new to matlab/programming in general and am trying to learn how to use the package "OMP Analysis" from geomar to figure out source water masses (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1334-omp-analysis). So far I've only tried running the test data provided in the package. I select the "interactive(listing)" option, select extended water mass analysis, then don't change anything else. Everything works fine until I get to the final prompt, "Do you want to see more graphic output?". I input "y" and get the following error message:

Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in contour2 (line 27)
para=A(st,:);

Error in omp2 (line 272)
        contour2

Error in omp2int (line 454)
omp2

Error while evaluating DestroyedObject Callback.

From what I can tell the error is originating in that one line from contour2 and then messing up subsequent commands. The dimension of A is a 2x204 double and the dimension of st is a 204x1 double.

Any help in figuring out this problem would be greatly appreciated!